# Can I backup primary keys from Heroku Postgres?

Tags: api, postgresql, heroku, primary-key, database-backups

We're building an API that currently exposes the database primary keys to select parameters. I'm concerned that pg_dump (and Heroku pgbackups which is based on it) apparently do not backup primary keys. (see [Postgres pg_dump dumps database in a different order every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178907/postgres-pg-dump-dumps-database-in-a-different-order-every-time))

If I need to upgrade our database or copy it to staging, I can use the Heroku follower or fork feature and preserve the primary keys. (see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-follower-databases and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-fork). However, exporting the database to use in development loses the ordering (see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export).

So, if I can't back them up, [Is it a bad idea to use a database table's ID as an external API identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403788/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-use-a-database-tables-id-as-an-external-api-identifier)

Should I consider creating a UUID column on each parameter table and expose that instead? (see http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids.html)

I find URLs like /v1/products?category=14,16&partner=3&q=plaid easier for developers to work with, but I'm concerned that I'm locking myself into Heroku by making it too hard to migrate away.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: `I'm concerned that pg_dump (and Heroku pgbackups which is based on it) apparently do not backup primary keys.` You appear to be misinformed, or your definition of `primary key` differs from mine. What exactly do you fear? What do you mean by "exposing the primary keys" ?

Comment: Are you trying to use tables `with oids`, using the oid as the primary key? If so: Bad plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm concerned that pg_dump (and Heroku pgbackups which is based on it)
>   apparently do not backup primary keys.

Don't be concerned. Of course they get backed up. That's not what the linked item is saying.

The item is saying that the order the rows get dumped in isn't guaranteed. That doesn't mean (id=1, name="fred") will lose (id=1) just that it might not be listed (in the backup file) as the first item. The only reason the poster cared was because he was trying to compare backup files as text.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my confusion. My query was ordered by the created_at date, which was identical (down to the second) for a bunch of the records. The pg dump and restore was showing those records in different orders. Changing the query to order by created_at and then id demonstrated that dump and restore work just the way they're supposed to.